# Addition in data Grid-view

Tags: c#, graph, windows-forms-designer

[Currently what I had so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3IUb.jpg): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3IUb.jpg]

I am trying to get the data  once the user key into the data grid view it will auto add data1 and data 2 together and display the total but it did not work here is my code so far I managed to get them to add up with an addition button

```
      private void dataGridView1_CellStyleContentChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStyleContentChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var a = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[0].Value = a;

            var b = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Value = b;

            var c = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[2].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[2].Value = c;

            var d = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[3].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[3].Value = d;

            var f = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[4].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[4].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[4].Value = f;

            var g = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[5].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[5].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[5].Value = g;

            var h = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[6].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[6].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[6].Value = h;

            var i = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[7].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[7].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[7].Value = i;

            var j = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[8].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[8].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[8].Value = j;

            var k = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[9].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[9].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[9].Value = k;

            var l = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[10].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[10].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[10].Value = l;

            var n = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[11].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[11].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[11].Value = n;
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Never run");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: you can short whole code small by looping over  all the rows in dgv

Comment: Hmm but what I want is like when the value for data 1 and data 2 is key in it will auto calculate the total and display the total value at the total column